# Android View Pager Rotation

Tags: android, rotation, android-viewpager, fragment, swipe

my App works with a View Pager like in this Example (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

Does someone know a way to make the View Pager rotate the Fragments endless?

For Example with 4 Fragments

User switches from Fragment 3 to 4 and make a right swift, so the Pager switches to Fragment 0

So if u ever swipe right you get something like this

0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> .....

thanks for reading :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a library implementing this feature:
[LoopingViewPager](https://github.com/imbryk/LoopingViewPager)

Comment: this looks like the right think
leading the Viewpager to believe that there are x. Fragments + 2 and redirect the position of the overlapping Fragments to the real Fragments......
But i hope the was a not so dirty way to deal with it ;-)